# Trying to hide/show partials based on if a input has text node.js handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, handlebars.js

so I have a page. there's a search bar. if the search bar has no text inputted, the page displays two partials, one for featured apps and one for most popular. but if someone inputs any text at all into the search bar then the featured apps and most popular apps partials disappear and the search results partial shows up. instead what happens is neither partials load. there's just a big blank space where they should be.

I tried doing this with jQuery but was having no luck. so now I'm back to trying to use dynamic partials but am also having no luck with that. if this can only be done with something like jQuery please let me know.

I was briefly trying to use a handlebar helper but I could not link it to the `input id="searchApps"` element without throwing an error because it keeps saying `searchApps` is undefined.

index.hbs (if this is missing any divs it's cause it's just part of the code)

```
<div class="col-2 offset-1">
  <div class="column-side">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <input id="searchApps" type="text" placeholder="Search apps...">
      {{!-- so once someone types the first character here the searchResults partial should render. and it should be dynamic so results should further refine with each additional character typed--}}
      {{>sidebar}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{{#if 'searchApps.length === 0'}}
  <div id="searchResultsHomePage">
    <div class="col-7 offset-1">
      {{>searchResults}}
    </div>
  </div>
  {{else}}
    <div id="homePageNoSearch">
      <div class="col-7 offset-1">
        {{>featuredApps}}
      </div>
              
      <div class="most-popular-grid">
          {{>mostPopularApps}}
      </div>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

here is the jQuery I tried in the index.hbs file just before the `</body>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#searchApps').on('change', function(){
      if ($(this).val() == ""){
          <div id="homePageNoSearch">
          <div class="col-7 offset-1">
            {{>featuredApps}}
          </div>
          
          <div class="most-popular-grid">
            {{>mostPopularApps}}
          </div>
        </div>
      } else {
          <div id="searchResultsHomePage">
            <div class="col-7 offset-1">
              {{>searchResults}}
            </div>
          </div>
      }
  });
</script>
```

so anyone know how I can do this?

thanks

Comment: Just to confirm: Your Handlebars template is rendered on the server, but you are trying to update it when an input value changes on the client?

Comment: @76484 yes. when I read it that way it makes me think I should probably try and use something front end like jQuery to get it done

Comment: That makes sense, but where do the search results come from and how do they get into the template? (ie., are they dependent upon what is typed into the input?)

Comment: @76484 I have a search function I can share. they come from a database and I get the data with a kinda long get call that filters through a variety of json keys and values. I tested the search function out on a blank, standalone page and it worked as expected so I'm not worried about that. and yes the results are dependent on what is typed into the input. I can update my code to include my search function if that helps.

Comment: @zamanda: Does the above mean that you fetch the results with an AJAX call? If so, what is the format of the returned data (ex., JSON, HTML string)?